# Earth-type sports in Star Wars universe

Tags: star-wars

Apart from droid NFL-style football and board games are there any examples of sports similar to ours? I.e., snooker/pool, football/soccer, tennis, etc?

Comment: _ahem_ podracing _ahem_ :p

Comment: @Jenayah yeh...em..I know......oops, had little sleep and brain not awake yet!

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Sports

Comment: Lightsaber fencing.

Comment: To the extent that poker can be called a sport, we see something very like it featured prominently in *Solo: A Star Wars Story*..

Comment: Poker is not a sport, nothing against it as I play but doesn't fall into board game category for me

Comment: horseracing : fathier racing

Comment: Asking this question now makes me feel stupid. FYI I have seen the Star Wars films many many time ps but my head isn't working too well last few days, thanks for keeping me right :)

Answer (score 4):

Starwars.com ran a two-part blog on this subject:

[THIS IS PODRACING: SPORTS IN THE STAR WARS GALAXY, PART 1](https://www.starwars.com/news/this-is-podracing-sports-in-the-star-wars-galaxy-part-1)

[TAKE ME OUT TO THE BALL GAME: SPORTS IN THE STAR WARS GALAXY, PART 2](https://www.starwars.com/news/take-me-out-to-the-ballgame-sports-in-the-star-wars-galaxy-part-2)

They list the following sporting activities that certainly relate to Earth sports. I will name the in-universe sport followed by the the Earth analogue in parenthesis, but some may not have a direct link or not enough information to provide a guess.

- **Racing with Machines**

  - Podracing (auto racing)
  - Swoop Racing (auto racing)
- **Racing with Legs and Animals**

  - Ronto Racing (horse racing)
  - Odupiendo Racing (ostrich racing)
- **Ball sports**

  - Smashball
  - Shockball (dodgeball)
  - Grav-ball/Zoneball (basketball)
  - Wegsphere
  - Huttball (capture the flag)
  - Limmie/Bolo-ball
  - Nuna-ball and Gulliball (American football)
  - Greenputt (golf)
- **Martial arts and boxing**

  - Pugil (mixed martial-arts)
  - Shockboxing (boxing)
  - Teräs Käsi (generalized martial-arts)
- **Recreational sports**

In addition to lead up of the release of *Attack of the Clones*, an official in-universe website named [HoloNet News](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/HoloNet_News_(original_website)) regulary ran a ["Sports"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sports) column.

Answer (score 1):

In the videogame Knights of the Old Republic, there is a combat arena on Taris.  I don't know if you'd count that as a sport, but the audience seems to, and the real world considers Mixed Martial Arts a sport.

Also in Knights of the Old Republic, A card game, [Pazaak](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Pazaak/Legends#Appearances), is very popular and can be played in many locations.  I don't know if you'd count that as a sport, but we have the [World Series of Poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Series_of_Poker), and the Star Wars universe seems to take Pazaak about as seriously.

Answer (score -1):

In the club scene of Attack of The Clones, we see a screen broadcasting a droid sport match. In the Zare Leonis books, he played some type of sport.

Comment: OP already mentioned droid football

Comment: oh, I was just kind of being lazy; i'm trying to become trusted